# got error 3300 when trying to save raw photo and its alternate photo to iOS album

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, camera, avfoundation

I found that it performs normal when not passing the alterPhoto.
This is my code

```
let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
        options.shouldMoveFile = true
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges{
            let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
            let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
                       options.shouldMoveFile = true
            creationRequest.addResource(with: .photo, fileURL: self.rawFileURL!, options: options)
            if let a = alterPhoto{
                creationRequest.addResource(with: .alternatePhoto, data: a, options: nil)
            }
        }completionHandler: { s, e in
            print(e)
        }
```

This is the code from apple's own document in this address,which is not a full project but an article with code pieces:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/photo_capture/capturing_photos_in_raw_and_apple_proraw_formats

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges {
     
            // Save the RAW (DNG) file as the main resource for the Photos asset.
            let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
            options.shouldMoveFile = true
            creationRequest.addResource(with: .photo, 
                                        fileURL: rawFileURL, 
                                        options: options)

            // Add the compressed (HEIF) data as an alternative resource. 
            let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
            creationRequest.addResource(with: .alternatePhoto, 
                                        data: compressedData, 
                                        options: nil)
            
        } completionHandler: { success, error in
            // Process the Photos library error.
        }
    }
```

I really don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue but was able to get it working by switching the order of the HEIF and RAW: set the HEIF as the primary and the RAW as the alternate:

```swift
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges {
            // Add the compressed (HEIF) data as the main resource for the Photos asset. 
            let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
            creationRequest.addResource(with: .photo, 
                                        data: compressedData, 
                                        options: nil)

            // Save the RAW (DNG) file an alternate resource for the Photos asset.
            let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()
            options.shouldMoveFile = true
            creationRequest.addResource(with: .alternatePhoto, 
                                        fileURL: rawFileURL, 
                                        options: options)
            
        } completionHandler: { success, error in
            // Process the Photos library error.
        }
    }
```

Update (2023-10-22): I also ran into an issue where the thumbnail displayed by Photos would be in the camera's native orientation (but opening up the full-size image was fine). I tested combinations of RAW/HEIF first, and using `addResource` as either `data` or `fileURL`.

TL;DR: use `addResource(with: .photo, data: heicData, options: options)` and `addResource(with: .alternatePhoto, fileURL: rawURL, options: options)`.

Where H = HEIF and R = RAW, I came up with the following results:

| Primary | Alternate | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| H/Data | R/Data | Error 3300 |
| H/URL | R/Data | Error 3300 |
| H/Data | R/URL | Good |
| H/URL | R/URL | Thumbnail not rotated |
| R/URL | H/Data | Error 3300 |
| R/Data | H/Data | Error 3300 |
| R/Data | H/URL | Displayed as 'RAW' instead of 'JPEG + RAW' in Photos |
| R/URL | H/URL | Displayed as 'RAW' instead of 'JPEG + RAW' in Photos |

Summarized:

- The alternate photo must be added using `addResource(with:data:options:)` instead of `addResource(with:fileURL:options:)`.
- The RAW file must be added as the `.alternatePhoto` or Photos will not (at least not in the UI) recognize the HEIF.
- If the primary photo is added using `addResource(with:data:options:)`, it does not correctly read orientation metadata when generating the thumbnail.